# Checking children for attribute in conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to see if the `<ul id="sortable">` has less than 3 `<li>` children and each child does **not** contain the `qual="qualX"` (where 'X' is an integer and 'qual' is an attribute).

There is a 3x2 grid `<div id="qualities">` that when a `<div class="quality">` is clicked, it will add a `<li>` to `<ul id="sortable">`.  The adding part works, but I want to make it so you can't add the same `<li>` more than once and not have more than 3 `<li>` total.  Right now, only the 3 `<li>` restricter is working; the "don't add the samea thing twice" code is not, as it's always true right now (apparently).

My logic code is

```
$(".quality").click(function() {
    if($("#sortable").children().length < 3 && $("#sortable").children("li").each().attr("qual") !== $(this).attr("qual")) {
        $("#sortable").append("<li qual=" + $(this).attr("qual") + ">" + $(this).text() + "</li>");
    }
});
```

whereas the HTML that is using this is

```
<ul>
    <li style="display:inline-block;">
        <div id="qualities">
            <div style="width:600px;overflow:hidden;background:blue;">
                <div class="quality" qual="qual1" style="width:200px;float:left;">
                    Quality 1
                </div>
                <div class="quality" qual="qual2" style="width:200px;float:left;">
                    Quality 2
                </div>
                <div class="quality" qual="qual3" style="width:200px;float:left;">
                    Quality 3
                </div>
                <div class="quality" qual="qual4" style="width:200px;float:left;">
                    Quality 4
                </div>
                <div class="quality" qual="qual5" style="width:200px;float:left;">
                    Quality 5
                </div>
                <div class="quality" qual="qual6" style="width:200px;float:left;">
                    Quality 6
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li style="display:inline-block;">
        <div id="priority">
            <ul id="sortable">
                <!--<li>Item 1</li>-->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>


<div id="priority">
    <ul id="sortable">
        <!--<li>Quality 1</li>-->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
... && !$("#sortable").children("[qual=" + $(this).attr('qual') + "]").length
```

This selects children that have the matching `qual` attribute using the attribute selector.

---

You should probably use `data-qual` over `qual`.